# How can I use multiple browser versions at one time?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, firefox, web-browser

On Windows I can use Utilu Firefox collection (there also ie collection on his site).

How can I use multiple browser versions to see how my website works in different versions of different browsers in OS X?

For example I want to install [browsers with biggest market share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_market_share#Summary_table):

- Internet Explorer
- Firefox 3.6, latest and previous
- Google Chrome latest and previous
- Safari (any older versions possible)
- Opera

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Firefox

[Firefoxes](https://github.com/omgmog/install-all-firefox) is a shell scripts that will install all major versions of Firefox on OS X, and set up separate profiles so you can use them simultaneously. Currently it installs:

- Firefox 2.0.0.20
- Firefox 3.0.19
- Firefox 3.5.9
- Firefox 3.6.28
- Firefox 4.0.1
- Firefox 5.0.1
- Firefox 6.0.1
- Firefox 7.0.1
- Firefox 8.0.1
- Firefox 9.0.1
- Firefox 10.0.2
- Firefox 11.0
- Firefox Beta
- Firefox Aurora
- Firefox Nightly
- Firefox UX Nightly

You can set it up so it only installs the specific versions you want.

Optionally, the script can install Firebug for each version of Firefox too.

It will also set icons that contain the version number:

[image]

### Safari

For Safari, check out [Multi-Safari](http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/).

### Chrome/Chromium

For Chrome/Chromium, install any version you want, change the app name from `Chromium.app` to e.g. `Chromium 19.app` for clarity, then [disable auto-updates](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates) for that version.

### Opera

Download old Opera versions here: ftp://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/mac/

### IE

Get VirtualBox and then run [this `ievms` script](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms). It will automatically download legal Windows images for testing purposes and set up virtual machines for every IE version you need.

Comment: Note: Multisafari works only for those OS's listed, i.e. you can't install safari 5.1.* on Mac Mavericks.

Comment: For IE, one can also go directly to the source modern.ie site for the VMs, though the GitHub script simplifies the install I guess.

Comment: Important Multisafari note: "**I’m no longer making up-to-date version of Multi-Safari.** _Newer Safari releases make it difficult to create self-contained version, and when they’re possible they usually won’t work on different OS versions, making them rather pointless..._"
**Are there any alternatives to Multisafari?**

Answer (score 2):

[MultiFirefox](http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox/) supports what you need, and seems to have good reviews. A drawback with it is that it doesn't support keeping multiple versions open simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

## Internet Explorer

Of course there is [Internet Explorer for Mac (PPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_for_Mac) but it's not very useful because it's based on different rendering engine (Tasman). It will run on OSX versions with Rosetta support. It can be downloaded from [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20051221154243/www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads.aspx?pid=download&location=/mac/DOWNLOAD/IE/ie5_osx.xml&secid=30&ssid=10&flgnosysreq=True).

Some [Windows Internet Explorer versions](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=25) do work in wine (winetricks helps a lot):

[image]

## Safari

There is [multi-safari](http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/) project. There are 1.x - 4.x versions and they may work or not depending on your OSX version (look at [compatibility grid](http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/#compatibility-grid) on his site).

## Firefox

I've found, that it's enough just to rename .app and then run it with different Firefox profiles.

- download all required version
- copy .apk`s in temporary place an rename them so you can distinguish one version from another
- put all renamed version to /Applications folder
- run needed firefox with -ProfileManager option and make a profile for each firefox (just in case)

Answer (score 2):

While not actually on your machine, you can also use a web application like [BrowserShots.org](http://browsershots.org/) to deliver you screenshots of the page rendered in a multitude of browsers or something like [Adobe's BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#).

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned BrowserLab but after april its not free. I'll try BrowserShots. Thanks.

Comment: If one want's more than screenshots, I'd recommend SauceLabs.com. Of all the multibrowser over the web services available online, at last check, they are the only one that offers a freemium account that doesn't have a trial expiration. And you can use it to do manual testing of different browser versions (or automation as well).